# How can I create subplots for each column of my data set and use color map to distinguish lines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset in a long format that looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxcVr.png)

So, two categorical columns and 96 variable columns.

I want to plot these values in a single figure but for each categorical column, have a distinct subplot. I started off simple and applied this code to get this result:

```
cluster_filter=1 # Assign the variable for cluster selection

tfo_filtered_cluster_df=tfo_labeled_df[tfo_labeled_df['CLUSTER_ID'] == cluster_filter]

grouped_df = tfo_filtered_cluster_df.groupby(['YEAR_SEASON']) 
season_color_group = tfo_filtered_cluster_df['YEAR_SEASON'] 

def legend_without_duplicate_labels(ax):
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    unique = [(h, l) for i, (h, l) in enumerate(zip(handles, labels)) if l not in labels[:i]]
    ax.legend(*zip(*unique))

color_map = plt.cm.get_cmap('Paired', len(season_color_group.unique()))
color_dict = dict(zip(season_color_group.unique(), color_map(np.arange(len(season_color_group.unique())))))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,20), layout='constrained')

for name, group in grouped_df:
    x = group.columns[5:]
    y = group.iloc[:, 5:]
    ax.plot(x, y.T, label=name, color=color_dict[name])

ax.set_xticks(range(96))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
legend_without_duplicate_labels(ax) 
plt.show()
```

This gave me the following result, which is ok and correct:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyaZU.png)

So this is the plot with the color being grouped by the values of column YEAR_SEASON.

What I want to achieve now is have another plot next to it but with the colors being grouped by the values of MEASURE_DAY. I have strugled so far to come up with something that works how I expect. My best attempt so far is to have the two plots in a single figure with this code:

```
`num_colum = tfo_filtered_cluster_df.shape[1]-96 # Extract the number of plots based on the number of categorical columns present in the ds

plt.figure(figsize=(30, 20))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1.5, wspace=0.1)

for yi in range(num_colum):
    ax = plt.subplot(num_colum, 2, yi + 1)
    for column in tfo_filtered_cluster_df.columns[-96:]:
        ax.plot(tfo_filtered_cluster_df[column], "k-", alpha=0.2)
    # ax.set_xticks(range(96))
    # ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
    ax.set_title(f"Regroupement par {tfo_filtered_cluster_df.columns[yi]}")
    

plt.suptitle("Visualisations pour cluster " + str(cluster_filter+1), fontsize=16)
plt.show()`
```

This worked in producing both plots in a single figure but everything else seems off: the xticks are unreadable, the lines are not ok,etc. Not to mention that I haven't yet applied the color map. Here is the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR1wF.png)

I feel like I'm very close while being way off at the same time. ChatGPT hasn't helped a lot so here I am.

Can someone help me out?

I have tried multiple iteration of the same code or a variant of it to no clear result.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a link to a little slice of your data?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: `df.sample(frac=<fraction of the data just enough to plot a fine figure>, axis=0).to_csv('filename.csv.gz', sep='\t')`